# How do you route from an MVC project to an MVC ApiController in another project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've been struggling with this problem for at least 4 hours now, trying every solution I could find.

My main project is set up with Asp.Net and MVC which works great routing to controllers within the project.  I'm integrating a library that exposes a JSON api that uses ApiControllers in another project but I can't get the main project to route to anything in the library project, it just returns a strait 404.

In my main project global.asax:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaxd}", new { allaxd = @".*\.axd(/.*)?" });
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*less}", new { less = @".*\.less(/.*)?" });

        //ignore aspx pages (web forms take care of these)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");

        //ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Nexus.Controllers");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "testapi",
            "testapi/{controller}/{action}",
            new
            {
                controller = "User",
                action = "Get"
            },
            new[] { "Nexus.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            // Route name
            "Default",
            // URL with parameters
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

    }
```

In my library project UserController:

```
namespace Nexus.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        public Object Get(string id)
        {
            var guid = new Guid(id);

            var user = crm.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == guid).FirstOrDefault();

            return new
            {
                id = user.UserId,
                name = user.UserName,
                email = user.Email,
                extension = user.Ext,
                phone = user.Phone
            };
        }
    }
}
```

None of the URLs that I expect to work do:
/testapi
/testapi/User
/testapi/User/Get
/testapi/User/Get?id=1

They all return 404.

I've even used the route debugger to verify that the routes appear to be set up correctly:
[image: routes]

What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose you've added the external library as a reference of your project?

Comment: Yes, my project is using lots of the data model from the library project.

Comment: A bit confused by the Action method 'Get' that you're using. I am used to actions returning an [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(v=vs.98).aspx)

Comment: The ApiController does not have to return an ActionResult.  I should have mentioned that the library works fine in another project returning JSON results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing standard MVC controllers (deriving from the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class) and API controllers (deriving from the `System.Web.Http.ApiController` class). Your UsersController is an API controller.

So if you want to configure Web API routes you need to use the `MapHttpRoute` extension method and not the `MapRoute` which is only for standard MVC controllers.

Like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "testapi",
    routeTemplate: "testapi/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also notice that in a RESTful API you do not specify the action name in the route. It is assumed from the HTTP verb used to consume it. Here's a [`good article`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) I recommend you reading about RESTful routing in the Web API.